# Why is three.js scene not rendering in my svelte app?

Tags: javascript, debugging, animation, three.js, svelte

`Scene.svelte`

```
<!-- Bind a container first then onMount add the renderer to this container -->
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import * as THREE from 'three';
    let container;
    onMount(async () => {
        const scene = new THREE.Scene();
        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

        const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
        renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        renderer.toneMapping = THREE.ACESFilmicToneMapping;
        renderer.toneMappingExposure = 1;
        renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
        container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
        const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
        const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        scene.add( cube );

        camera.position.z = 5;
    });
</script>

<div id="container" bind:this={container}/>
```

`App.svelte`

```
<script>
  import { onMount, onDestroy } from "svelte";
  import Navbar from './components/Navbar.svelte';
  import Hero from "./components/Hero.svelte";
  import Content from "./components/Content.svelte";
  import About from "./components/About.svelte";
  import Work from "./components/Work.svelte";
  import Projects from "./components/Projects.svelte";
  import Accordion from "./components/Accordion.svelte";
  import Skills from "./components/Skills.svelte";
  import Experience from "./components/Experience.svelte";
  import Contact from "./components/Contact.svelte";

  import Scene from "./components/Scene.svelte";

  import './assets/stylesheets/content.css';
  import './assets/stylesheets/navbar-862-and-up.css';
  import './assets/stylesheets/navbar-862-down.css';
</script>


<!-- <Navbar/>
<Content>
  <Hero slot="landing-section"/>
  <About slot="about-section"/>
  <Work slot="work-group-section">
    <Projects slot="projects-section">
      <Accordion slot="accordion-group" repos={included}/>      
    </Projects>
    <Skills slot="skills-section"/>
    
    <Experience slot="exp-section" min_year={min_year} max_year={max_year} on:changeYear={fetch_contribs}/>
  </Work>
  <Contact slot="contact-section" on:sendMail={send_mail}/>
</Content> -->
<Scene/>
```

I've commented some code for simplicity but here is my main App.svelte file and the Scene.svelte file is actually from a folder in the main directory of App.svelte called components.

I've tried installing threlte and the reason why I resorted to just installing three.js without threlte was because initially even I had problems with threlte because it rendered nothing in my screen but a "sad face" type of svg

I've tried threlte, rendering with a simple live server and an .html file, and now this, and nothing works. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to [render your scene](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Creating-a-scene):

```js
onMount(() => {
    // ... snip ...
    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
    animate();
});
```

Some other unsolicited Svelte advice:

- Your listed `onMount` does not need to be `async`, since you're not using `await` anywhere.
- Avoid `id`'s in components. Components should be reusable, `id`'s must be unique by definition. `bind:this` is almost always sufficient, including this case :)
- Avoid importing CSS files, this makes them global and leak everywhere. Prefer [scoped styling](https://svelte.dev/blog/the-zen-of-just-writing-css), possibly using `svelte-preprocess`'s [`src` attribute](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess#external-files).